# An error has occurred. : No connection string named "EmployeeDBEntities' could be found in the application config file

Tags: c#, asp.net, api, entity-framework, webapi

I am facing an error message when I try to run my ASP.Net web API.

I have two projects in a solution. 
1- Class library for Entity Class Model. 
2- Web API Controllers.

[image]

Error message when I try to run this application.

[image]

Comment: In which app the app.config is? Is it in the expected project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I could see in the Solution explorer, the app.config file is not in the startup project. So you could copy the app.config file to the EnoloyeeService project. It should work then.